# Error when retrieving message from Service Bus queue

Tags: azure, go, azure-servicebus-queues

I trying to pull messages from azure service bus queue using Go, but I got an error when running the code. Here is my code.

```
func Example_queue_receive() {
   ctx, cancel :=context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),10*time.Second)
   defer cancel() 
   connectionString :="Endpoint=sb://{my_service_name}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName = RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey={my_shared_access_key_value}" 

    // Create a client to communicate with a Service Bus Namespace.
    ns, err := servicebus.NewNamespace(servicebus.NamespaceWithConnectionString(connectionString))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Create a client to communicate with the queue.
    q, err := ns.NewQueue("MyQueueName")
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("FATAL: ", err)
    }

    err = q.ReceiveOne(ctx, servicebus.HandlerFunc(func(ctx context.Context, message *servicebus.Message) servicebus.DispositionAction {
         fmt.Println(string(message.Data))
         return message.Complete()
     }))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("FATAL: ", err)
    }

}
```

This is the error:

> link detached, reason: *Error{Condition: amqp:not-found}

Comment: Not related to the error but there seems some mistake in your code, HandlerFunc is supposed to return `error` instead of `servicebus.DispositionAction`.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the error information in the Github repo, and I found the code [`ErrorNotFound              MessageErrorCondition = "amqp:not-found"`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-go/blob/98fec12aac8b52e81ead4bdec8738987b8c33fa1/message.go#L100), but there is not any explaination for the error.

I compared it with [`Exception types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#exception-types) in C# from the offical document `Service Bus messaging exceptions` and my testing, I think it's the same as below.

[image]

In my environment `go version go1.11.3 windows/amd64`, I run the similar code without an existing queue `MyQueueName`, I got the similar error below.

> FATAL:  unhandled error link xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx: status code 404 and description: The messaging entity 'sb://.servicebus.windows.net/**MyQueueName**' **could not be found**. TrackingId:f9fc309d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8fccd694f266_G42, SystemTracker:.servicebus.windows.MyQueueName, Timestamp:2019-01-25T09:45:28

So I think the error means your Queue `MyQueueName` in your code is not existing in your Azure Service Bus, you should create it first before to use.

Meanwhile, as @JerryLiu said, your code below has some mistakes.

> ```
> err = q.ReceiveOne(ctx, servicebus.HandlerFunc(func(ctx context.Context, message *servicebus.Message) servicebus.DispositionAction {
>          fmt.Println(string(message.Data))
>          return message.Complete()
>      }))
> ```

According to the godoc for [`azure-service-bus-go`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-go), the parameter type of `servicebus.HanderFunc` method must be `HandlerFunc` which is a function return `error`, not `servicebus.DispositionAction` in your code.

[image]

And the method `message.Complete` should be passed a parameter `ctx` (a `context` object) and return `error` that not match `servicebus.DispositionAction`. The `message.CompleteAction` method return `servicebus.DispositionAction` , but not suitable in the reciving message code.
[image]

Please refer to the example of godoc [`Example (QueueSendAndReceive)`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-go#example-package--QueueSendAndReceive) to modify your code.

Comment: @Jerry Liu ,@Peter Pan...I tried the example you provide.But I got another error again. 
 >cannot convert func literal (type func(context.Context, *servicebus.Message) error) to type servicebus.HandlerFunc